# how to fix error in escape sequence which has backslash it self as a special character

Tags: json, bash, escaping, backslash

how  to fix error in escape sequence which has backslash it self as a special character.
error in parsing escape sequence characters through bash script.

we have below json data in a file test.json

```json
          "specialties": {
            "type": "array",
            "description": "list of the provider's specialties",
            "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "A specialty of the provider provider's",
              "nullable": true,
              "example": "[\"Psychiatry\"]"
            }
          }
```

we are trying parse this data into a string with below code.

```bash
data=$(cat test.json )
data=${data//\"/\\\"}
data=$(echo \"$data\" | tr -d ' ')
echo $data
```

above code output string

```
\"specialties\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"description\": \"list of the provider's specialties\", \"items\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"A specialty of the provider provider's\", \"nullable\": true, \"example\": \"[\\"Psychiatry\\"]\" } }
```

this output string used with below curl request is throwing below error

```bash
 curl -s  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --location --request POST "${HOST}/api/v1/projects" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" -d  '{"name":"'${PROJECT_NAME}'","openText": '${data}',"source": "API"}'

{"timestamp":"2022-12-10T14:00:32.384+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 34273]","path":"/api/v1/projects"}
```

we use this (https://jsontostring.com/) site to convert above json data to string and  it produces below output string  which is working with our java app.

```json
"\"specialties\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"description\":\"listoftheprovider'sspecialties\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"Aspecialtyoftheproviderprovider's\",\"nullable\":true,\"example\":\"[\\\"Psychiatry\\\"]\"}}"
```

difference between two output strings is one extra backslash\ character at the beginning and end of the word "Psychiatry"

```
 #not working string part
  \"[\\"Psychiatry\\"]\" 

#working string part
\"[\\\"Psychiatry\\\"]\"
```

why is that extra backslash character is producing in this case and how to get that output.

Comment: Can you use `jq`?

Comment: What would be the final JSON that you want to generate? Can you provide it raw like you did with the test.json? It should be something like `{"name": "myproject", "onpentext": ???, "source": "API"}`

Answer (score 0):

after adding below code and using jq tool, it is fixed now. thanks fravadona.

```
data=$(cat test.json )
openText=$(echo $data |  jq . -R |  tr -d ' ')
echo $openText

#above code output string

"\"specialties\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"description\":\"listoftheprovider'sspecialties\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"Aspecialtyoftheproviderprovider's\",\"nullable\":true,\"example\":\"[\\\"Psychiatry\\\"]\"}}"
```